# R/arrow: trouble reading parquet data files

Tags: r, dataframe, parquet

I am attempting to read-in a relatively large parquet file (~4M rows, ~100 columns). **Can someone please help me interpret the following error messages?**

I have no trouble reading/writing files in csv form after converting them to parquet files, I am attempting to read it in using `arrow::read_parquet` to little avail. When I attempt to read it in, I am getting the following errors.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
par <- file.path(dir, 'path', 'to', 'my', 'file.parquet') %>% 
           read_parquet
glimpse(par)

# Error in setalloccol(newx) : 
#  Internal error: length of names (0) is not length of dt (109)
```

and I get

```
names(par)
#NULL
```

Having said this, I *can* observe that the csv version and the parquet version have the same number of rows and columns

The other common error I receive is:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "..row.names..", value = 1:3279887) : 
   replacement has 3279887 rows, data has 0
```

Comment: Can you check if the data starts from first row itself and also if the header length is different from the contents.  Also, try with the option `as_data_frame = FALSE`

Comment: thanks @akrun for these! removing empty rows after read-in does not produce different results so I'm afraid that I'm misinterpretting the direction. `as_data_frame = F` results in an "<Object containing active binding>". Can this be converted to a dataframe? Having trouble here

Comment: It returns an arrow table with `as_data_frame = FALSE`.  I am not sure whether you need to convert to data.frame to do some transformations.  According to [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html) some of the tidyverse functions still work on the arrow table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was specific to the arrow version and has since been patched. Was previously using version 1.0.0 but cannot replicate the error on 4.0.1